# Modify and restore PowerShell prompt from a module

Tags: powershell, scope

I'm writing a PowerShell module for interacting with a remote service. When connecting to the remote service (via a function in the module), I want to prepend the username to the prompt. Upon disconnecting, I want to remove the username.

I thought I could accomplish this by copying the global `prompt` function, then restoring it upon disconnect:

```
# Doesn't work
function Connect {
    Copy-Item function:prompt function:prompt_old
    function global:prompt { "[Username] $(prompt_old)" }
}
function Disconnect {
    Copy-Item function:prompt_old function:prompt -Force
}
```

However, `Copy-Item` doesn't make a copy in the global scope. Thus, `prompt` throws a `CommandNotFoundException` and the disconnect function can't replace `prompt` with `prompt_old`.

Is there a way I can modify, then restore, the PowerShell prompt from module functions?

Comment: Try storing it in a global variable like `$global:prompt_old = get-content function:\prompt` then modify and apply with `set-content function:\prompt $global:prompt_old`

Comment: @Graimer A-ha, that works. Why not post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great! :) I didn't have a computer to test it on, so since it was so short I just used a comment until someone had tested it. Added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store the function in a variable while you work.

Backup using:

```
$global:prompt_old = get-content function:\prompt
```

Then you can modify the prompt, and recover it later using:

```
set-content function:\prompt $global:prompt_old
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me to modify the function in-place rather than replacing it. Thanks!